# How to stop sending read receipt for message read using OpenPop.NET

Tags: c#, openpop

I am reading all unread emails for an email id using `OpenPop.Net` in C#. The application is sending read receipt to the sender for all the message read by OpenPop.

Please suggest a way to stop sending read receipt.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an openPOP issue, but rather a server issue. Since I'm not sure what mail server you're using, here's an article on how to disable this behavior in [Exchange 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2294143) (it's the same for 2010). Hope this helps.